# Does a Router use NAT to assign it's own IP to the packet and then the use PAT to figure out where to send the response?

Tags: networking, router, ip, nat

Does a router use NAT when receiving a packet from a private IP:PORT to change the source IP on the packet to its own public IP and then when it receives the response packet back, use PAT and the PORT to figure out which private IP the request came from?

Why do we have private IP's if this is the case when we could just use the MAC and port to get the packet to the router and then use the public IP from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When most people say "NAT" they really mean what the IETF standards call "NAPT", which in Cisco proprietary jargon is called PAT.

NAPT gateways do NAPT in both directions. In some cases the port doesn't need to be changed, and some NAPT implementations choose not to change the port in those cases.

We use private IPs behind NAPT gateways because it is convenient to use IP on the LAN rather than invent some way of doing TCP/UDP/ICMP/etc. directly on Ethernet without a network layer (layer 3).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I have another question regarding Port-Forwarding so I would appreciate another moment of your time. Say I set up 2 servers inside my private network, then I would have to port forward each of them to allow for communication with the public network. Each of them would get a separate port. Then the only thing differentiating my 2 servers from the public eye would be the difference in ports (ignoring potential DNS problems). The public IP would stay the same for both servers. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. By the way, in general, SuperUser's Q&A format works best if new questions are posted as separate Question posts rather than as comments on a previous Question or Answer. If my Answer resolved your Question, click the checkmark outline next to my Answer to mark this as resolved.